# Flask Nginx HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I hope everyone is doing ok.
I am sorry to bother with this problem, but I tried every single suggestion and advice found online but none of them worked for me.
Here is what I have.

I got a simple blog project running in docker containers.

- Docker container for development environment(flask and Postgres)
- Docker container for production environment(Flask + gunicorn + nginx)

With the Dev container i dont have any problem. My redirects url work just smooth and nicely. But the problem raise on the production container. If i try to register (POST methods) or upload profile picture or write a blog, as soon as a submit the website crash with the message on the console "HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND", seems that nginx cannot redirect my POST request from any page.

This is my route configuration and my nginx configuration.

- NGINX

```
upstream blog {
    server web:5000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://blog;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 5M;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

- ROUTES CONFIG

```
users = Blueprint('users', __name__)


@users.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(
            form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username=form.username.data,
                    email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been created succesfully', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('users.login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)


@users.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('main.home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check your e-mail and/or password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

I hope I gave enough information to help you to understand my problem and thank you so muhc in advance for your help

**UPDATE**
I found the source of my troubles XD and thought to share the solution.
In my specific case, i had problem here:

`proxy_set_header Host $host;`

I changed it to:

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`